# Count unique values in Access

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to count unique values in Access. I have looked at some other posts, have tried using properties, setting unique to yes and looked into DCount. I'm looking at the wrong things or doing something wrong as I'm not getting this to work. I'm not very familiar with SQL programming. I use Design View when building queries. Below is a sample of what I want to accomplish:

```
Client  Amount
1        100
1        100
1        100
2        100
2        100
3        100

Count 
Unique Sum
Client Amount
3       600
```

I can accomplish this in two-steps doing first a query to group by client, then a second query count the clients and sum the amounts. Can I do this in one step? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: it would be better to provide information on the table you are querying rather then the result.   Nothing in the result you provide shows uniqueness as client has 1 three times with the same value yet the total is 600 for amount.  It is a bit unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for the lack of clarity. I was trying to simplify the question. The real situation I am working with has many tables and hundreds of thousands or rows. If I do a simple count of client, the query would return 6. The sum of all the amounts paid is 600. What I am looking for is count of unique clients (which is three in this example). $600 was received in total. This $600 came from 3 clients. Does that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more SQL orientated in the explanation but the underlying premise is the same: In short you need to create a table in your From Clause that you use in your select. You can then use that table to count and sum your totals.

```
Select Count(ClientAmounts) as ClientTotal, Sum(ClientAmounts) as AmountTotal
From
(
    Select <tableName>.Client, 
    Sum(<tableName>.Amount) as ClientAmounts
    From <tableName>
    group by <tableName>.Client
)
```

Comment: Thank you! I was able to get that to work on the simple example. Now I'll try on the real one.